# Listener does not listen for triggered event - LIVEWIRE

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-livewire, livewires

I have a button on my blade that calls a select method, this method emitted an event but it is not arriving

Button blade:

```html
<div class="ml-auto">
    <button class="br-button secondary circle" type="button" aria-label="Selecionar" wire:click="selecionar({{ json_encode($user) }})">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Method Select: which is inside the search component

```php
public function selecionar($user)
{
        $this->emit('userSel', $user);
        $this->buscaNome = "";
        $this->usuarios = [];

}
```

Method userSel: which is inside the create component

```php
protected $listeners = ['userSel'];

public function userSel($user)
{
    $this->state = $user;
}
```

I've already tried to issue directly from the blade.

Comment: Are you not getting the data in the ``userSel`` or the ``selecionar`` method?

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab. emit should create a 2nd request (Livewire2) and you can check whether the listener gets executed:

```
public function userSel($user)
{
    dd($user);
    $this->state = $user;
}
```

In your case the create component should be present on the page

Comment: It doesn't arrive in my userSel method,

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `{{ json_encode($user) }}` of the function
to `'{{ json_encode($user) }}'`

```
wire:click="selecionar('{{ json_encode($user) }}')"
```